# Determine Whether SQL Command is an UPDATE command by regular expressions

Tags: c#, sql, regex, entity-framework

I've lots of SQL commands from Entity framework's interceptors such as following:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Products]
SET [Name] = @0
WHERE ([Id] = @1)
```

How can I determine that this command is an `UPDATE` command ?

I've written following regular expression:

**`(update)? [a-z0-9-]+ (set)`**

But it does not support commands in multiple lines and the command text should be in one line, and it does not support table names with schema and `[]` characters in their names.

It only supports simple SQL commands as following:

```
UPDATE Products SET [Name] = @0 WHERE ([Id] = @1)
```

Note:
I'm using this regular expression and `IDbCommandInterceptor` feature of Entity Framework to provide `WITH (ROWLOCK)` table hints to SQL server for `UPDATE` commands, so I need a regular expression from `UPDATE` keyword to `SET` keyword because `WITH (ROWLOCK)` should be inserted right before `SET` keyword.

Consider following code:

```
String updateCommandRegularExpression = "(update)? [a-z0-9-]+ (set)";

Boolean isUpdateCommand = Regex.IsMatch(commandText, updateCommandRegularExpression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline); // You may use better regular expression pattern here.

if (isUpdateCommand)
{
    Boolean isSnapshotIsolationTransaction = sqlCommand.Transaction != null && sqlCommand.Transaction.IsolationLevel == IsolationLevel.Snapshot;
    // Transactions with Snapshot isolation level have more complicated table hints to enable rowlock.

    String tableHintToAdd = isSnapshotIsolationTransaction ? " with (rowlock , updlock) set " : " with (rowlock) set ";

    commandText = Regex.Replace(commandText, updateCommandRegularExpression, (match) =>
    {
        return Regex.Replace(match.Value, " SET ", tableHintToAdd, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); // You may use better regular expression here.
    }, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

    command.CommandText = commandText;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Putting locks on rows instead of locking entire table, when you're updating only a few records, has several performance benefits, because other transactions will continue their work on on other records of the same table which are not being updated, so we'll have fewer transactions which are waiting.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
'[; \t]*[Uu][Pp][Dd][Aa][Tt][Ee][ \t]'
```

Basically, an update command is one where the first word is `update` -- at least for simple commands.  If you allow common table expressions (`with` statements), then the logic is more challenging.

EDIT:

I would suggest the following approach.  Use the above expression to determine if the command is an update.  Then, replace "set " with " with (ROWLOCK) set".  This will handle the cases where the table might have special characters or use an alias.  The one downside is it will not help if the table contains "set".

Because you are doing this in C#, you can test to see if the characters before and after the set are white space characters rather than alphanumeric.

Note:  This will not work correctly if the `update` already has hints.  You can look for that by looking for "with" before the "set".

Comment: I've added extra notes to my question, could you please take a look at that again ? Thanks so much. No, I've no with statements in my updates.